# Make input text disabled/readonly in IE9 and below using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text, input

Anyone have an idea how to do this?

I have tried JavaScript below didn't work.

```
element.readOnly="true";
element.readonly="readonly";
element.disabled="disabled";
```

Tried the below jQuery has not worked either.

```
$("#id").attr("disabled","disabled");
$("#id").attr("disabled",true);
$("#id").attr("readonly",true);
$("#id").attr("readonly","readonly");
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there another way to achieve this for ie9 and below?

Thanks

Comment: Should work. Maybe `element` wasn't what you thought it was at the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are setting the ***attribute*** value on the element, then you need to use a string that is equal to the attribute you are setting. For example, if you are setting `disabled` attribute, then you should set it equal to `"disabled"`.

#### HTML

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" />
```

#### JavaScript

```
$("#id").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

If you are setting the ***property*** value, then you need to use a boolean value: `true` or `false`. Properties only get set in JavaScript:

#### JavaScript

```
element.disabled = true;
```

In your first example above, you are setting JavaScript properties to strings, instead of boolean values. This is why it didn't work.

Here are the possibilities that will work for you:

```
//Any of the following work
element.readOnly = true; //It is readOnly, not readonly
element.disabled = true;

$("#id").attr("disabled", "disabled");
$("#id").attr("readonly", "readonly");

//Additionally, you can use jQuery's prop() method, but I don't recommend it.
$("#id").prop("disabled", true);
$("#id").prop("readOnly", true);
$("#id").prop("readonly", true); //jQuery will bridge the gap here, and fix this for you.
```

It's also important to understand that `disabled` and `readonly` serve different functions:

- `disabled` Means that you can't interact with the element at all. Elements that are `disabled` are immutable, meaning their value can't be modified. They also are omitted from form submissions.
- `readonly` Means that you simply can't change the value of the element.

Comment: Why don't you recommend jQuery's `.prop()` (since it is intended for exactly this purpose)

Comment: @Spudley Because it is slow in comparison to the other methods which are just as simple to use, if not more so.

Comment: @Spudley Here is a [`jsperf`](http://jsperf.com/jquery-prop-vs-javascript-prop) to back that claim up.

Comment: No surprise; raw DOM will *always* trump a library. But I thought you were talking about `$().prop()` vs `$().attr()`. It isn't entirely about performance (`$().prop()` exists in jQuery separate from `$().attr()` for a reason, and that reason isn't perf related), but anyway I've [modified your test to include jQuery attr](http://jsperf.com/jquery-prop-vs-javascript-prop/2), and yes, attr is faster than prop, but a it's pretty marginal difference compared with the raw DOM method.

Comment: `jQuery.attr()` and `jQuery.prop()` do completely different things. Why would I be comparing the two? There is a big difference between a DOM element attribute and a JavaScript property. The point is that `jQuery.prop()` is highly inefficient, and shouldn't be used unless it offers some extreme benefit (probably never). Yes, it can save you from having to loop over a jQuery collection, and apply a property to each element in a for loop. So it *barely* increases readability in some scenarios, but that readability is offset by a rather large performance loss. Especially for a large collection.

Comment: The problem turned out to be a browser setting issue with JavaScript, thanks for the comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1):

`disabled` and `readonly` are properties not attributes.

This distinction is important because jQuery provides a different method for setting properties vs attributes.

You should use `$().prop()` not `$().attr()` to set them.

```
$("#id").prop("disabled",true);
$("#id").prop("readonly",true);
```

Using `.attr()` will not work. (it used to work, way back in the days of jQuery 1.5, but not since they introduced `.prop()` in jQuery 1.6)